# How to write a Spring property Converter for percentage to double

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want a Spring-Boot app to bind percentages to `int` or `double` properties without custom parsing per setter. Since it is doesn't have built-in support via [NumberUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/NumberUtils.java), this means using their Converter API but I can't find the way to do that - augmenting `Number`/primitive parsing is more complex than simply supporting a new type.

I want this minimal example to work, though equally happy if parsing `50%` returned `50d` instead of `0.5d`...

```java
public class MyApp {
  @Bean
  public MyApp bean(@Value("50%") double percent, @Value("0.5") double real) {
    assert percent == real;
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args); }
}
```

Comment: Spring Conversion is from one type to another. You are doing String to Double conversion for which a converter is already present. You want to interpret Strings and based on that calculate something, that isn't something that is part of the Spring type conversion system. It would work if you had a `Percentage` class you could then create a `StringToPercentageConverter` (and vice-versa).

Comment: True, I could create a bespoke `Percentage` but that still puts effort onto app dev to know about it and ends up with a dubious pattern of `void setValue(Percentage)` setting a `double value;`

Comment: You should be setting a `Percentage` not a `double` in the first place.

Comment: If Java supported aliases sure but I don't feel great about wrapping primitives in classes just to get them into the system. There's plenty of prior here: spring NumberUtil supports all sorts of patterns into `Number` ... just not this one.

Comment: `NumberUtils` is for converting a number (hex or plain number) into a number, it isn't for converting a string into something else. Nor is Spring `Converter` system usable for this as it is for type conversion, not for interpreting strings and parse them into something else.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer as no one proposes anything better than defining a bespoke class.

This is a clumsy example, you can make the parsing/formatting as flexible as you wish but doing it with a static `valueOf(String)` method means it gets picked up automatically by Spring (and other libraries like Jackson) without needing any further bespoke converters.

```java
public class Percent {
    public final double value;

    public static Percent valueOf(String source) {
        if ('%' == source.charAt(source.length() - 1)) {
            return new Percent(Double.parseDouble(source.substring(0, source.length() - 1)) / 100);
        }
        throw new NumberFormatException(source + " not a percentage");
    }

    public Percent(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(value * 100) + '%';
    }
}
```